# composer make script

Tags: php, composer

есть у меня composer пакет, я его устанавливаю в проект, и он добавляет в vendor/bin/myProject мой пакет для исполнения. Но я не хочу вызывать через vendor/bin/myProject execute и тд... Я хочу сделать composer someScript и все. Для этого мне нужно руками добавить в раздел scripts SomeScript...

Как я могу автоматизировать это, чтобы при установке пакета в composer.json добавлялся нужный мне скрипт сразу

Comment: Посмотрите как сделан, например, skeleton у symfony. При создании скелета проекта там создаётся composer.json в котором уже всё есть

Comment: @ArchDemon посмотрел щас - нету там ничего такого

Comment: @ArchDemon https://github.com/symfony/skeleton тут смотрел